# Proposal - Sandbox for custom programming languages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

## A Sandbox for custom programming languages

> This was adapted from [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5088/38891). I'm posting it here because it sounds like a [feature-request](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

I've noticed a lot of people have invented custom programming languages (ever heard of Pyth?) I've also noticed that people post challenges they think would be cool in the Sandbox. Here is my proposal: **a Sandbox where you can post your custom languages and interpreters.**
You write a submission like this:

## LANGUAGE NAME

Some syntax
`3+3`
Adding!
`l=3`
Variables!

#### Interpreter

`interpreter's code here`
People then can use the language with credit (if allowed?), comment on it, etc.
Is this a good idea?

Comment: Between the lack of multiple files and SE's char limit, you'd be hard-pressed fitting anything useful in a post like that...

Answer (score 8):

*In this post, I'm speaking as a user, not a moderator.*

I don't really think this is on-topic here, and I'm also not sure how much use it would be anyway.

If this is about creating a repository of esoteric languages, there's no point in reproducing [esolangs.org](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page) in a place and software that wasn't meant for it.

If this is about increasing the popularity of golfing languages, I don't think a post on Meta PPCG will help much either. The best thing you can do for popularising your own language is simply to use it in the challenges on Main.

Lastly, the interpreter's code doesn't really belong or fit into an answer here. Most of the language authors will have their language in some version control system, often hosted publicly (e.g. on GitHub or Sourceforge). That's also where the documentation belongs. Duplicating this information here on meta is, again, not where it belongs.

Comment: All right. Is there any way I could try to salvage it?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I can't tell, because I don't know what you're trying to achieve with this proposal. What problem would such a repository be solving? I think that's where you should start.